# Fill background image instead of stretch on screen resize

Tags: html, css

I have a background image that adapts to the screen height and is on full width. Problem is, when I resize my width, the image stretches instead of fill. Also, the content that should be below it overlays the image totally.

This is my code so far.

HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/2560x1000" class="img" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="content">
    <!-- some content -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    z-index: -1;

}

.img {
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

And here's a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/anm5sqft/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.bg-section {
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:100vh;
}
<div class="bg-section" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/2560x1000)"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1wurw0zu/

Answer (score 2):

You use "background-position" and "background-size" but you doesn't have a background, because your image is not a background, it's an image.

Try this :

HTML

```
<div id="bg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#bg {
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/2560x1000");
}

body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Example with JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anm5sqft/4/)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and sample.

Comment: The content was still overlapping with the image.